# IntelliJ - Groovy start - Error: Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

**In similar questions** I could **not** find a sufficient answer. I followed the IntelliJ tutorial for Groovy, but it did solve the solution. Finally I solved it via a 1A4 Maven file.

For getting started more easy, maybe you could help me and others with Groovy in IntelliJ.

What did I do:

1. I installed the Groovy SDK
2. I started IntelliJ, created a new Groovy project and I could see the library was added.
3. After creating my first Groovy class, a compile error mentioned:

> Error: Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined

[image]

I double checked that the library is there. And I also added the library to the module via the File > project structure > libraries. I get this result:

[image]

Added on request: I added project structure > modules > dependencies: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your `.iml` file looks like?
I repeated all steps from your message and have successfully run `GroovyDemo.groovy` class without any errors.

My `.iml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="groovy-2.4.15" level="application" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Make sure what you have groovy library inside. If you don't have it, you need to open project setting and add it manually into `Libraries` or `Global Libraries`.

I'm using IDEA 2018.1.6 UE. What is your version?

**EDIT 1:**

I finally reproduce your error.

1. I delete .idea folder from my project scope;
2. I open old project and it recreate the whole structure;
3. After that I see the same error when trying to run groovy class

I fix it by manually add groovy library to the project dependencies.

Comment: The line with the library was there: 
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="groovy-2.5.1" level="application" />
Notice that when running Maven with the next line, then all workds fin. <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.3" level="project" />

Comment: How did you install groovy? Maybe you get only GDK, eg. I used https://sdkman.io to do get groovy and put it on the project.

Comment: On windows via standard installer: groovy-lang download of SDK. I have IJ 2018.1 professional. In the lib folder of the Groovy download I see the groovy-2.51 jar.

Comment: Then you download only Groovy SDK, try to install groovy from this link: https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/Distributions/groovy-2.4.15-installer.exe (version for 2.5.1 is not available yet, as I can see) and import it in IDEA.

Comment: In the Groovy SDK is a groovy-2.51 jar with all other jars. 
See my added picture. The library is there. I also added the library via the project struture. Still the same result.

Comment: Could you, please, attach one more screenshot with `Project Settings -> Modules -> Dependencies`?

Comment: In that moment I install IDEA CE on Windows with the same JDK as yours.
1) I download Groovy Binary from the official site and unzip it.
2) Open IDEA and create new Groovy project.
3) Create new Groovy SDK and select root folder of unziped files (groovy-2.5.1) which contains bin/conf/lib etc
4) Create new class GroovyDemo with println "Hello World"
5) Run it with Ctrl + Shift + F10 and it was successfully compiled and finished.

Comment: I give up - I did exactly what you said - it just won't work at my computer. 
Thank you for all your work. I upvotes ... and I will continue with Maven Groovy.

Comment: Let's check the last thing. Could you, please, attach one more screenshot with `Project Settings -> Modules -> Dependencies`?

Comment: I added the screen shot. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176866/discussion-between-dmitry-shaldin-and-tjm1706).

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl+shift+alt+s`.place in Project Structure.then setting your Libraries,attending to your groovy install-file-folder lib--> groovy-***.jar。